# Django annotate add interval to date

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, annotations

I am using postgres database with Django 2.2. I need to combine date and time field in model and add an interval of one day in it. I have done first part like this.

```
Model.objects.annotate(
    end_dt=models.ExpressionWrapper(
        models.F('date') + models.F('end'),
        output_field=models.DateTimeField()
    )
)
```

Now I have to add 1 day to `end_dt`. I have done this with plain sql like this.

```
SELECT 
       "db_shift"."id",
       (("db_shift"."date" + "db_shift"."end") + INTERVAL '1 day') AS "end_dt"
FROM 
     "db_shift";
```

How can I achieve this using django ORM? Or is it even achievable?

Comment: what is the field type of `date` and `end` ? Is both are `DateTimeField` in models? Can you show the relevant parts of the models?

Comment: @JPG `date` is `DateField` and `end` is `TimeField`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After a bit of experimentation I have found that adding timedelta from datetime works just fine :)

```
import datetime


Model.objects.annotate(
    end_dt=models.ExpressionWrapper(
        models.F('date') + models.F('end') + datetime.timedelta(days=1),
        output_field=models.DateTimeField()
    )
)
```

Comment: Won't work in case your interval depends on other table columns.

Answer (score 3):

For people coming here and looking for a way to add interval depending on a column from the table itself, you can proceed as following:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    quantity = ...
    created = ...


class Interval(Func):
    function = "INTERVAL"
    template = "(%(expressions)s * %(function)s '1' DAY)"

...

MyModel.objects.annotate(
    expiry_date=ExpressionWrapper(
        F("created") + Interval("quantity"),
        output_field=models.DateTimeField(),
    )
)
```

The code above will add N days to the `created` date field, where N is the `quantity` field.